# How does FRAPS autostart?

Tags: windows-7, fraps, autostart

This is sort of related to my other question, but where does windows store the autostart ("Run fraps when windows starts")  data for fraps. I have checked msconfig under the startup tab, the startup folder and searched the registry for "fraps", but nothing of interest came up.

This is also the case for bandicam, proXPN and other applications

Comment: Use [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to figure out how and why something is starting.

Comment: Might be a Task listed in the Scheduled Task to run on log-on, Have a look at the Tasks listed in `Task Scheduler` and report back. [Task Scheduler How-To](http://www.howtogeek.com/123460/htg-explains-how-windows-uses-the-task-scheduler-for-system-tasks/)

Answer (score 0):

There are some common locations on a Windows system (since '95) that allows for programs to start on boot:

- Folder: %USERPROFILE%\Start Menu\Programs\Startup (This where you can place shortcuts to programs that you want loaded at startup)
- Folder: %ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Start Menu\Programs\Startup (Same thing, but will load for all users of Windows)
- Registry: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
- Registry: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce (An item should appear, and disappear after next boot)
- Service: Run "services.msc", these aren't usually your typical program, but more like background tasks.

Fraps uses the 1st of these as far as I  know.

As mentioned by David, the utility AutoRuns will gather all of these (and more) together into one easily viewable list.